# Paperclip multiple storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I want to move my assets folder to Amazon S3 and since it has a big size, during the transaction i need to upload files both in my local storage and amazon s3 through paperclip.

Is there a way to configure paperclip to store uploaded files both on filesystem and amazon s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'd benefit from this:

> http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/asynchronous-s3/

What you'll have to do is firstly upload to your local storage, and then "asynchronously" upload to S3

This is typically done through the likes of [`Resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [`DelayedJob`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) (as the tutorial demonstrates), and will require you to run some sort of third-party processing engine on your server (typically Redis or similar)

From the tutorial:

```
### Models ###

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :local_image,
                    path: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    url:  "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  has_attached_file :image,
                    styles: {large: '500x500#', medium: '200x200#', small: '70x70#'},
                    convert_options: {all: '-strip'},
                    storage:         :s3,
                    s3_credentials:  "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    s3_permissions:  :private,
                    s3_host_name:    's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
                    s3_headers:      {'Expires'             => 1.year.from_now.httpdate,
                                      'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment'},
                    path:            "images/:id/:style/:filename"

  after_save :queue_upload_to_s3

  def queue_upload_to_s3
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ImageJob.new(id) if local_image? && local_image_updated_at_changed?
  end

  def upload_to_s3
    self.image = local_image.to_file
    save!
  end
end

class ImageJob < Struct.new(:image_id)
  def perform
    image = Image.find image_id
    image.upload_to_s3
    image.local_image.destroy
  end
end

### Views ###

# app/views/people/edit.html.haml
# ...
= f.file_field :local_image

# app/views/people/show.html.haml
- if @person.image?
  = image_tag @person.image.expiring_url(20, :small)
- else
  = image_tag @person.local_image.url, size: '70x70'
```